# How can I filter out private events in a calendar query for Exchange WebDav?

Tags: exchange-server, webdav, exchange-server-2003

I need to pull all non-private items from a user's calendar in Exchange 2003. I've gotten the following to work, which pulls all of their items (including the Private field):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<g:searchrequest xmlns:g="DAV:" xmlns:mapi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/">
    <g:sql>
        SELECT "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/Private", "urn:schemas:calendar:uid", "urn:schemas:calendar:location", "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject", "urn:schemas:calendar:dtstart", "urn:schemas:calendar:dtend", "urn:schemas:calendar:busystatus", "urn:schemas:calendar:meetingstatus", "urn:schemas:calendar:instancetype" 
        FROM Scope('SHALLOW TRAVERSAL OF "%s"') 
        WHERE NOT "urn:schemas:calendar:instancetype" = 1 AND "DAV:contentclass" = 'urn:content-classes:appointment' AND "urn:schemas:calendar:dtstart" > '2003/06/01 00:00:00' AND "mapiPrivate" = 0 
        ORDER BY "urn:schemas:calendar:dtstart" ASC
    </g:sql>
</g:searchrequest>
```

However, when I try to add the Private field to the `WHERE` I get a `BAD REQUEST` error in response. The following code is how I added the Private field to the `WHERE` clause.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<g:searchrequest xmlns:g="DAV:" xmlns:mapi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/">
    <g:sql>
        SELECT "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/Private", "urn:schemas:calendar:uid", "urn:schemas:calendar:location", "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject", "urn:schemas:calendar:dtstart", "urn:schemas:calendar:dtend", "urn:schemas:calendar:busystatus", "urn:schemas:calendar:meetingstatus", "urn:schemas:calendar:instancetype" 
        FROM Scope('SHALLOW TRAVERSAL OF "%s"') 
        WHERE NOT "urn:schemas:calendar:instancetype" = 1 AND "DAV:contentclass" = 'urn:content-classes:appointment' AND "urn:schemas:calendar:dtstart" > '2003/06/01 00:00:00' AND "mapiPrivate" = 0 AND "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/Private" = 0
        ORDER BY "urn:schemas:calendar:dtstart" ASC
    </g:sql>
</g:searchrequest>
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to request the PR_SENSITIVITY property (DASL name http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x00360003).
For the private apppoitments its value will be SENSITIVITY_PRIVATE (=2)